How to set timeout API SOAP webservice ASP.NET C#
There are two applications which communicate via web service to transfer a XML.
The application "A" sends a request (Hello, I want the XML) and the application "B" creates the XML for the application A.
However the application B need sometimes 2min to create the XML and what I research so far that the web service has a standard timeout of 90seconds and application A never receives the XML.
So the developers from application A increased the timeout
to 3min (180000), see below:
public GetData GetSO(Envelope request)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_urlGetSO);
        client.Method = 'Post';
        HttpWebResponse response;
        client.Timeout = 180000; 
        // ....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}        

but the problem still persists, any idea?
also we have the web.config on the aplication B side configured as below:
Well looking for all options on the side where application "B" we have the configuration for the web.config below:
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"/> 
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/> 
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>


since debug = "true", it should overrides request execution timeout making it effectively infinite. So we should never experience time outs at all...? why is it happeing? Does it make sense to include  in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[version]\config\machine.config or is it in web.config enough?
